# JavaScript stops functioning after adding type=module to src tag in HTML (Using Flask)

Tags: javascript, html, json, flask

What I thought would be the easiest part of my project has turned into a Herculean effort. All I wanted to do was get data from a JSON file to then display on my website. Prior to using a JSON file, I hard coded some data to test my filter/search functionality, all of which I wrote in JavaScript. The code worked perfectly, so I decided to move the data to a JSON file as I am expecting to have a lot more data in the future and can't have it hardcoded. However, I have been unable to get data from the JSON file successfully. I tried using require('./data.json'), but apparently I can't just use require like that. I then tried importing the file, which only works if I go back to the html and add type="module" to the src tag. This then allows all of the data to display on the webpage, however, the function that allows me to filter by category no longer works. When I click on the buttons, I get no response. I used Inspect to get the console to find the error, and the output is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: filterProject is not defined
```

The search functionality still works, and I suspect this is because that code isn't inside a function. Thus, I don't know why filterProject is supposedly not defined when the other JS code works. Here is all of my code:

```
import projects from './data.json' assert { type: "json" };

const path = "http://localhost/static/images/";
//ADDING THE HTML, IGNORE
for(let i of projects){

    let card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add("card", i["category"], "hide");

    let imgContainer = document.createElement("div");
    imgContainer.classList.add("image-container");
    let imageOne = document.createElement("img");
    imageOne.setAttribute("src", path.concat(i["imageOne"]));
    imgContainer.appendChild(imageOne);
    card.appendChild(imgContainer);

    let container = document.createElement("div");
    container.classList.add("container");
 
    let name = document.createElement("h3");
    name.classList.add("project-name");
    name.innerText = i["projectName"].toUpperCase();
    container.appendChild(name);

    let student = document.createElement("h4");
    student.classList.add("student-name");
    student.innerText = i["studentName"].toUpperCase() + " mentored by " + i["mentor"].toUpperCase();
    container.appendChild(student);

    let category = document.createElement("h6");
    category.innerText = i["category"].toUpperCase().replace("_", " ");
    container.appendChild(category);

    card.appendChild(container);
    document.getElementById("projects").appendChild(card);
}
//FILTERING (DOESNT WORK)
function filterProject(value){
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button-value");
    buttons.forEach((button) => {
        if(value.toUpperCase() == button.innerText.toUpperCase()){
            button.classList.add("active");
        }else{
            button.classList.remove("active");
        }
    });

    let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
    elements.forEach((element) => {
        if(value == "all"){
            element.classList.remove("hide");
        }
        else{
            //having a space messes it up, make it _
            if(element.classList.contains(value.replace(" ", "_"))){
                element.classList.remove("hide");
            }
            else{
                element.classList.add("hide");
            }
        }
    });
}
//SEARCH (WORKS)
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener
("click", () => {
    let searchInput = document.getElementById("search-input").value;
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".student-name");
    let cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
    elements.forEach((element, index) =>{
        if(element.innerText.includes(searchInput.toUpperCase())){
            cards[index].classList.remove("hide");
        }
        else{
            cards[index].classList.add("hide");
        }
    });
});
//INTIAL STATE
window.onload = () =>{
    filterProject("all");
};
```

Here is the HTML just in case as well:

```
<div class ="wrapper">
        <div id="search-container">
            <input type="search" id="search-input" placeholder="Search student name here..."/>
            <button id = "search">Search</button>
        </div>
        <div id ="buttons">
            <button class = "button-value" onclick="filterProject('all')">All</button>
            <button class = "button-value" onclick="filterProject('Creative Project')">Creative Project</button>
            <button class = "button-value" onclick="filterProject('Developing Voice')">Developing Voice</button>
            <button class = "button-value" onclick="filterProject('Interdisciplinary Fusion')">Interdisciplinary Fusion</button>
            <button class = "button-value" onclick="filterProject('Personal Writing')">Personal Writing</button>
            <button class = "button-value" onclick="filterProject('Curriculum Designer')">Curriculum Designer</button>
            <button class = "button-value" onclick="filterProject('Internship')">Internship</button>
        </div>
        <div id = projects></div>
    </div>
    <script type = "module" src = "{{ url_for('static',filename='javascript/script.js') }}"></script>
```

If it matters, I am using Flask as my web framework. I'm not sure if that has any impact on anything, but it has created some obstacles when I've tried to create a live server to solve this issue. Thanks in advance for any replies!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is how to load json files locally.

One solution is

1. Start a local server e.g. http://localhost:8080
2. Then use `fetch()` to retrieve the `json` file

For example, if your `data.json` file was located within the same folder where you have your `html` file and where you started your server, then your code could be something like

```
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/data.json")
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
     // Add code to process your data
    })
```